# How to programmatically access the Google API key in google-services.json

Tags: android, google-api, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

The app uses Google Cloud Messaging and contains a google-services.json file which itself contains Google API authentication info, including the API key. GCM functions as expected.

The app contains a testing facility that sends a GCM message using HTTP, and it needs the API key. How do I access that key, the one stored in google-services.json? I do not want to use GoogleCloudMessaging to send the messages (I'm using OkHttp and it does the job nicely).

Hopefully it is not necessary to duplicate it in the app.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Sorry, a bit late to the game here...

The `google-services.json` file gets parsed and its values get added to an `xml` which you have access to:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

In your case, you could get the api key with:
`activity.getResources().getString(R.string.google_api_key);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works perfectly.
Although Android Studio IDE flags that the String resource doesn't exist, when you build your app it becomes available.

Comment: Sorry, where do I type that command, and which language is it in?

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the API key off your GoogleCloud platform then go to credentials and you can grab your API key off of there. 
https://console.developers.google.com/

Is that what your looking for?

But if you need to access it (which is should never change unless your change the json file itself) Then you could just parse the json file with a parser. But thats adding more work than needed. I would just copy and paste it from the web.

Ok I see what you going for try using this and using the NSDefualts
Store the token like this:

```
 if (registrationToken != nil) {
        self.registrationToken = registrationToken
        print("Registration Token: \(registrationToken)")
        //store the registation token for use in the postData function in the login page
        self.loginInformation.setObject(self.registrationToken, forKey: "GCMToken")
        let userInfo = ["registrationToken": registrationToken]
```

And retrieve it anywhere in the project like this:

```
myNoteGCMID = loginInformation.objectForKey("GCMToken") as! String
```

Then if it changes you don't have to change it in but just one place. The change will occur everywhere you call it.

Comment: I have the key, that is not the problem. It is already stored in the project, but my own code needs the key too - the result is the key ends up stored in two places, and if it ever needed to be changed it is not good to have to remember to update it in two places.

Comment: Your updated answer seems to be referring to the push messaging registration ID, but what I want access to is the API key?

Comment: If its anything like the GCM api your code should grab it from the json file and you should not have to hard code it. I looked around and the only way is to either get it off the Google Console and place it in your code or get it out from the google service file. I guess you can parse it out yourself its only a json file. So just point to it where its stored and have a method to parse it out of the file